# How to decrypt a json response with gzip encoded data in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The Json response has encrypted objects which has to be decrypted to get the actual process. In android GZip was used .How can I achieve this  The sample Json is as mentioned below.Any help is really appreciated.

```
            {
                "Data": "1.´ABCD´1150275,11028´01-Jan-2021´8,000.00´",
                "Data": [
                    {
                      "Element": "8iMAAB+LCAAAAAAABADt1T8zBxwHgkefKcGh98Zcdz8FSqj9DMzK4d+L0Nj1tveNR2w6M8rRs3PJWBFDy"
                    },
                    {
                     "Element": "B1AV4bGp6JzQJI8ChnxzixrlT8vKnYHPwRM8zykKVn2gkceAFdxMwU0to"
                    }
                ],

    "Status": 1,
    "Msg": "Success",
    "APIVersion": "1.4"
}
```

Basically how to decrypt a Gzip string. The same process was done in android ,but im new to flutter
Android java code is attached. i want to achieve something like that in flutter

```
    public static String decompress(String zipText) throws IOException {
        byte[] compressed = Base64.decode(zipText, Base64.DEFAULT);
        if (compressed.length > 4) {
            GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed, 4,compressed.length - 4));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int value = 0; value != -1; ) {
                value = gzipInputStream.read();
                if (value != -1) {
                    baos.write(value);
                }
            }
            gzipInputStream.close();
            baos.close();
            return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

On way i tried was

```
  List<int> data  = utf8.encode(zipText);
  var deCompressedString = GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(data);
  print(deCompressedString);
```

Which throw exception

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid GZip Signature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decrypt zipped: [How to decode a Gzip Http Response in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535415/how-to-decode-a-gzip-http-response-in-flutter)

**EDIT**

decompress like this

```
 String decompress(String zipText) {
  final List<int> compressed = base64Decode(zipText);
  if (compressed.length > 4) {
   Uint8List uint8list = GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(compressed.sublist(4, compressed.length - 4));
   // print( String.fromCharCodes(uint8list));
   return String.fromCharCodes(uint8list);
  } else {
   return "";
  }
 }
```

Comment: @Android_id So does my answer help you?

Comment: @Android_id so what have you tried, and what bugs do you see? paste your partial code

Comment: @Android_id see my updated answer. you need to first decode the base64. after you get that decompressed string, use the json lib I mentioned above.

Comment: @Android_id show a sample `zipText`. and, try my newly updated answer (edited again just now)

Comment: @Android_id (1) show a **full** sample input data (2) show your android code

Comment: thank you for guiding through the solution. i have edited to your answer to the working code.i made the rest part working

Comment: @Android_id Happy to hear that!